# How to locate a user and show a page based on their language

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I'm trying to build a multi-language website. In my root folder I have `index.php` and 3 other folders: Arabic, French, English, each containing web pages. I would like to locate the user and redirect them to the folder of their language, and make English the default language. During the process I want it to be done in `index.php`, then redirect to the target folder (for exemple: `english/index.html`).

Comment: You need to look up the `IP` address of the visitor using PHP, and then use a service to resolve this IP address to a country. From here you can choose which template to display. Note that this would be possible in JavaScript (with AJAX), though you would have to change a lot of content, so you're better off using PHP. Also, this question is unfortunately too broad for StackOverflow; try implement something yourself, then come back here when you get stuck.

Comment: You can get `User Locale (language and region)` or  `User's Time Zone` to know about langauage or region of visited user,

Comment: You can add https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_translate.asp plugin.. so that you don't have to create multiple sites for multiple languages.

Comment: @AmanjotKaur thank you good idea but can i hide the top bar of google traduction and can i custom it with css?

Comment: Yes... you can do that... You can customize google translator CSS